# how to change the ubuntu logo which appears while booting the ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10

how can i replace ubuntu logo,(white logo with black background) which comes very first while booting (it also comes while shuting down) in ubuntu 9.10.
I am able to replace other images, which comes  after this image. I have done it by replaceing my images with the images present in /usr/share/images/xflash.But it is not possible to replace the mentioned image by this way.
Where the above mentioned image (white with black bg) will be stored? 
Thank you for answering...

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu uses [USplash](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/USplash) to do this.

You can configure it with [Startup Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/StartUpManager), and fill it up with themes you get from [here](http://gnome-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=160).

It is possible (but quite tricky) to make your own themes too, with a little bit of fiddling about; you need to compile the theme and tweak a fair few settings. [This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/USplashCustomizationHowto) goes into a bit of detail as to how you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace original images with your own, name it with the same name, if you are not familiar with programming, or name it whatever you want and update file ubuntu-logo.script.

When you finish all your changes with images or potentially in code, don't forget to update initramfs image:

> sudo update-initramfs -u

And before you make any change there, be sure to backup original files!!!!!!